# Replace Fedora Partition With Ubuntu

Tags: installation, 12.10, partitioning

So I tried installing Fedora along side Windows 7 and after a week of using Fedora, I can't stand it and I'm switching back to Ubuntu. I'm unsure of how to install Ubuntu in place of Fedora.

Below is the screen shot of the partitions I have. (Sorry for the low quality, taken from my phone) I'm not sure exactly which device I should be clicking on to install.

My gut says I should select the root of ext4 to install. I don't see anywhere that I can delete those partions, only formatting is an option.

Suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fedora is using LVM and by default the live CD does not have LVM installed. Furthermore, gparted does not manage LVM either.

LVM takes a physical partition and divides it into logical divisions.

Scroll down in the list of partitions and identify which partition was used for Fedora. You can delete or use that physical partition although you will also need to make a swap partition for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

1. Keep the ntfs partition for Windows
2. Remove any other partitions
3. On the free space, create a swap, a "/" in etx4 and a "/home", both in ext4.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the exact same problem and this is how I solved it:

1. I went to the console using `ctrl+alt+F6`. You can also do this from a terminal.
2. Then I used `lvscan` to see the Fedora's lvm partitions and then I used `lvremove` to remove the lvm partitions.
3. After this step I went back to the graphical partitioner (`ctrl+alt+F1`), but I was still unable to remove the partition that was used for lvm, so I went back to the console and removed the lvm partition with `cfdisk`. After that I simply let Ubuntu install itself alongside Windows.

I'm not sure step two was required. It's possible that I would have been able to remove the lvm partition directly from `cfdisk`. So you might save yourself some time by running `cfdisk` directly.